# Pytorch: Bernoulli "without replacement"

Tags: python, pytorch, probability, bernoulli-probability

Given a probability tensor, how can I use torch.bernoulli to generate multiple samplings while ensuring they are all distinct?
Is there any better way than the naive way, i.e., just sampling and re-trying if colliding?
Any method using other libraries (e.g., numpy, scipy) are also fine!